# How Can set default Parameter Binding in ASP.NET Core Web API

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net5

In all of my API [HttpPost] methods, I have to put [FromBody] before arguments and it is repeated work!
for example:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<JsonResult> Method([FromBody]MyModel model)
    {
        //CODE
        return Json(result);
    }
```

Is there any special setting or trick that say to Web API, your default Parameter Binding of  [HttpPost] is [FromBody]?

Comment: Hi, In asp.net core web api, it will bind data which from body by default.

Comment: @Rena When I remove [FromBody] before arguments, It does't bind. so I have to put it.

Comment: Hi, Does the controller contains ApiController attribute?